# Will a daemonset always be deployed to all nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

I'm wondering if a daemonset in kubernetes will always be deployed to all nodes.

My confusion comes from the following description of a daemonset

> A DaemonSet makes sure that all **or some** kubernetes Nodes run a copy of a Pod.

The "or some" part, implies that there are cases when some nodes won't run a pod. For my use case it would be important that all nodes would run an instance. What are the cases in which a node won't run an instance of a pod, even though it is deployed as a daemonset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on which target of nodes are selected.

> If you specify a .spec.template.spec.nodeSelector, then the DaemonSet controller will create Pods on nodes which match that node selector. Likewise if you specify a .spec.template.spec.affinity, then DaemonSet controller will create Pods on nodes which match that node affinity. If you do not specify either, then the DaemonSet controller will create Pods on all nodes.[DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-only-some-nodes)

Also I would  check the [taint and toleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#taints-and-tolerations) for Daemonset.

Comment: Thank you, that exactly answers my question!